# Pulling hair the all over the body

Tags: dogs

We have a dog the pulls his hair out all over his body and he is almost bald. He has also chewed his toenails of on his back leg plus pulled all his hair out there to he is so miserable and we don't know how help him. We tried giving him some Benadryl for allergies and it's not stopping any of this. We are at a loss on what to do to help him.

Comment: What does your vet say?

Comment: Welcome to pets.se Becky! Please check out the questions I have tagged to yours, they should have your answer :)